# How can I use one route53 record to point to two S3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-route53, s3-bucket

I have two buckets **a** and **b** with static websites enabled that redirect to original buckets **A** and **B**. I created two route53 record sets(A records) **slave-1** and **slave-2** pointing to each bucket **a** and **b**. I then created a **Master** record set(A record) with failover, **slave-1** as primary and **slave-2** as secondary. When I try to access the S3 contents using the **Master**, I get a 404 'No Such Bucket.' Is there a way that I can get this set up to work? If are there are any workarounds for configurations like this?

Comment: To identify possible workarounds, we need to understand... what problem would this solve for you?

Comment: There's a third party tool and it supports pointing to only one server. So, I am looking for a solution where I would be able to point to either of the buckets by not changing the DNS name in the third party tool.

Answer (score 1):

S3 *only* supports directly accessing a bucket using either one of the endpoint hostnames directly (such as example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com) or via a DNS record pointing to the bucket endpoint when the name of the bucket matches the entire hostname presented in the `Host:` header (the hostname my-bucket.example.com works with a bucket named exactly "my-bucket.example.com").

If your tool will be signing requests for the bucket, there is no simple and practical workaround, since the signatures will not match on the request.  (This technically could be done with a proxy that has knowledge of the keys and secrets, validates the original signature, strips it, then re-signs the request, but this is a complex solution.)

If you simply need to fetch content from the buckets, then use CloudFront.  When CloudFront is configured in front of a bucket, you can point a domain name to CloudFront, and specify one or more buckets to handle the requests, based on pattern matching in the request paths.  In this configuration, the bucket names and regions are unimportant and independent of the hostname associated with the CloudFront distribution.